# Is it possible to pay low gas price for low computation transaction?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, gas-price

I'm trying to update storage variable in my deployed smart contract every 5 minutes. Though this needs low computation power and therefore requires low gas amount, it is hardly payable as gas price for gas unit is too expensive.

I haven't tested in mainnet, only in rinkeby.

is it possible for my transaction to be minded with low gas price, lower than average, as it requires just updating storage variable(and that's it)?

Thanks.

Comment: if you are developer then switch to Polygon (Matic), it has low gas price

Comment: Is there any way to publish the data on-chain only when it's needed? Perhaps using a signed off-chain feed that's only published on-chain at the time it needs to be consumed?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister We can and that's the alternative way if we cannot update price oracle periodically.

Comment: @Nulik Can I get data from smart contract deployed on polygon from a smart contract deployed on ethereum mainnet?

Comment: @fdasdf you mean via `CALL` ? no. Polygon doesn't replicate the state of the contract working on mainnet , it is a new network, but it has low gas price

Comment: @Nulik Thank you! Then I may have to deploy all my contracts on polygon. Can I use bridge in code level not bothering user experiences?